# "Simple" physics problem without the solution

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

it's my first question here, i'm a french student in "classe préparatoire scientifique" and I find a problem on the net witch is :

> A slingshot consists of a rubber band that extends 3cm when you shoot with a force of 10N. I throw a pebble 20g having stretched elastic 20cm. How fast will the stone he kicked? We give the answer in kilometers per hour rounded to the unit. We neglect the inertia of the slingshot.

Well I'm ashamed of myself, but this problem get me angry ^^

I precise my reasoning :

So I name $\vec{F}$ the force exercise buy the elastic on the pebble and $\vec{P}$ his weight, so by Newton's law I have :

$$
\sum \vec{F_{ext}} = ma 
$$

Where $a$ is the acceleration

Then in the coordinate system $(O,\vec{u_x},\vec{u_y})$ and $\vec{{u_y}}$ the direction of $\vec{P}$,

$$
\vec{F}+\vec{P}=m(\vec{a_x}+\vec{a_y}) 
$$

becomes $$F=ma_x$$

Then I have $$a_x=\frac{F}{m} = 10^4 m.s^{-2}$$

Well now I don't know how to find the speed because if I integrate I will find the speed depends on time but not in distance because at $t=0$ the pebble has no speed and here we need the speed when it travels 10 cm (because the rubber band is hand in her to part I think)

Can you help me please ? 
Thank you very much by advance and sorry if I made some english mistakes :)

Comment: This is a conservation of energy problem. Consider the total mechanical energy before and after the pebble is ejected.

Comment: Hum well at the beginning the pebble has no cinetic energy so $E_{at beginning}$ is $E=m*F*h$ but I don't understand exactly what happends after for it, has it some potential energy + cinetic energy or just cinetic ?

Comment: This is primarily a conservation of energy problem. At the beginning of the problem the pebble is stationary, and thus has only potential energy. When the pebble leaves the slingshot it only has kinetic energy. Assuming no energy is lost to external factors (air resistance etc.) we can equate the two energies, and solve from there.

Comment: Well I find $v=\sqrt{2Rh}$ but my numerical application doesn'work, I try with F=100/3 N and h=0.1 m ; I also try with F=200/3 and h=0.2 m but this is not the solution the site want :/

Comment: Salut Shadock - I think your $E_{atthebeginning}$ equation is not correct because the force $F$ changes as the rubber band changes length. It should be ${1\over2} k x^2$ as in the answer just provided by Demosthene.

Comment: Yes I always forget somethings !!! :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you stretch the rubber band horizontally, and that the pebble doesn't start falling until after it's left the slingshot - that way, we don't have to worry about gravitational potential energy. Assumption number 2 will be that the pebble leaves the slingshot at $x=0$.

Conservation of energy tells you that the initial total energy $E_{tot,i}$ (slingshot cocked) must be equal to the final total energy $E_{tot,f}$ (pebble leaves the slingshot). We therefore need to consider the kinetic energy $E_{kin}$ of the pebble, and the potential energy $E_{pot}$ stored in the rubber band.

As you know:
$$E_{kin}=\dfrac{1}{2}m_{pebble}v^2$$
$$E_{pot}=\dfrac{1}{2}k_{rubber}x^2$$
The spring constant $k$ can be computed as:
$$k=\dfrac{\Delta F}{\Delta x}=\dfrac{10\ N}{3\ cm}\simeq 333,3\ N\cdot m^{-1}$$

Let's now compute $E_{tot,i}$ and $E_{tot,f}$:
$$E_{tot,i}=E_{kin,i}+E_{pot,i}=\dfrac{1}{2}mv_i^2+\dfrac{1}{2}kx_i^2=\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot 0,02\cdot 0^2+\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot 333,3\cdot 0,2^2\simeq 6,67\ J$$
$$E_{tot,f}=E_{kin,f}+E_{pot,f}=\dfrac{1}{2}mv_f^2+\dfrac{1}{2}kx_f^2=\dfrac{1}{2}\cdot 0,02\cdot v_f^2+\dfrac{1}{2}k\cdot 0^2=0,01\cdot v_f^2$$

And from conservation of energy:
$$E_{tot,f}=E_{tot,i}\Longrightarrow 0,01\cdot v_f^2=6,67\Longrightarrow v_f=\sqrt{\dfrac{6,67}{0.01}}\simeq 25,8\ m\cdot s^{-1}$$

Therefore, the pebble exits the slingshot at a maximal speed of:
$$v_f\simeq 93\ km/h$$

(Je peux aussi taper la réponse en français si ça t'arrange)

Comment: @Shadock I'm confused - your profile says you're in London, but you're a French student?

Comment: Oui je suis un étudiant français, mais j'ai passé trois ans à Londres avec mon père et je suis revenu en France pour la prépa :)

Comment: Et tu fais quoi comme prépa?

Comment: PC et oui j'ai vraiment honte d'avoir posé cette question ! :/ par contre un problème de diffraction bien hard ne me pose pas de problème en général ^^

Comment: C'est pas grave ^^ Dans ces problèmes-là, il faut s'en tenir aux données de l'énoncé et à des principes de conservation (énergie, quantité de mouvement, moment cinétique), après ça va tout seul. Et bon courage avec la prépa, c'est pas facile à ce qu'il paraît :)

Comment: La difficulté viens surtout de la quantité si tu réussis l ENS PC c'est un peu comme si tu avais une L2 en maths physique et chimie XD,  les notions ne sont pas différentes de celles de la fac